# vertically align text inside anchor tag doesn't work in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, anchor, vertical-alignment

I was trying to make a simple help button using "A" anchor tag. The thing is it works perfectly on Firefox, Chrome, OP, Safari. Now when I tried it on Internet Explorer 10, The text wasn't properly aligned in the middle. here is what I've done so far:

HTML

```
<a id="help-btn"><span>?</span></a>
```

CSS

```
#help-btn {
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: solid 5px #2F2F2F;

    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    text-align:center;

    background: #c100ff; 
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#help-btn span { 
    color: #22002D;
    font: 10em "bauhaus 93";
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
    line-height: 100%;

}
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd4kg/3/) sample. any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I've finally found the solution after 3 hours of digging deep, as stupid as may it sounds but the extra space was being added by the font "bauhaus 93". It renders correctly on all browsers except IE (that's a shocker). So I had to change it to another font and now it works perfectly. so if anyone face the same problem please do check the font that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

play with your line-height.

Try this :

```
#help-btn span { 
    color: #22002D;
    font: 10em "bauhaus 93";
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
    line-height: 10em; // CHANGE YOUR LINE-HEIGHT SIZE 

}
```

if the problem not fixed, try add display:block; to your #help-btn span

Comment: Now you just need to fix the size in hard of your button, try with : max-width:10em; and max-height:10em; , if not work, try with max-width:10em !important; and max-height:10em !important; 

Oh, and if the problem fixed, please mark this post is solved ;-)

Comment: Ok, so fix the size of your button in pixels or convert size of em to pixel if you want stay in em size!

Comment: its not working internet explorer is just adding extra space to the bottom of the text.. its really weird behavior..

Comment: Hum, iEx its really the sh.t browser.
And test with fix the size of your span in hard and add overflow:hidden!important;

Comment: its still not doing anything.. I've just added a border to the span.. and its showing that there is extra space at the bottom of the character..

Comment: Hum, hard!!! Sorry i've no iEx on my desktop and i dont make more help for u !!!

Sorry :(

Comment: unbelievable it was a problem from the font it self.. it adds extra space to the bottom.. wow I've wasted more than 3 hours on this..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the line-height attribute and that attribute must match the height of the div. In your case:

Try

```
#help-btn span { 
    color: #22002D;
    font: 3em "bauhaus 93";
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;

}
```

Comment: not working as well. a little bit different but same result.. not aligned

Comment: can u add the above snippet and have a look

Comment: try adding ur font 10em "bauhaus 93"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33174/discussion-between-abertil-and-robin-van-persi)